# Last last command shortcut in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a shortcut (key combination) in `emacs` to repeat the second last command? Or
third last command and so on? I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> +  <kbd>z</kbd>  
can be used to invoke the last command, but could not find a key combination for others!

Comment: Can you not pass a prefix arg?  Try `Ctrl` + `u`, `2`, `Ctrl` + `x`, `z`.

Comment: @RandyMorris seems like this runs the last command twice instead of running the last last command!

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the docs for `repeat-complex-command`, not `repeat`.  My apologies.

Comment: `repeat` is literally repeat. It repeats the same command that invoked it. A prefix arg is passed to that command. A prefix arg to `repeat-complex-command` lets you edit and re-evaluate the last complex command expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a related question: [Is there a (repeat-last-command) in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275842/is-there-a-repeat-last-command-in-emacs)

There is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105886/138470

Which looks like what you're asking for.